# angular directive not hitting directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

please helpme why anugular directive not hitting directive when i change text in it.

```
<div ng-controller="EmployeeController">
    <input type="text" message /></div>
```

**angular.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope) {....}
```

**Directive**

This is my directive

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .directive('message', function () {
          debugger;          return {
              //compile:function($scope,elem,attr){
              //   // console.log(attr.text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('message', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('keyup', function(event) {
                console.log(event.target.value);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <input type='text' message/>
</div>
```